# Access variable from include in blade template in php

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I have a blade template that includes other blade template.
Here is the main template called `accountnav.blade.php`

```
@if (count($subaccounts) > 0)
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       @foreach ($subaccounts as $account)
           <?php $p_link = $account->link?>
           @include('frontend.template.subaccount', array('p_link' => $p_link))
       @endforeach
   </ul>
@endif
```

and here is the included template titled `subaccount.blade.php`

```
<li {{count($account->children) > 0 ? "class = dropdown" : ""}}>
        @if(count($account->children) == 0 )
            <a href="{{$account->link}}">{{$account->name}}</a>
        @else
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" onclick="return false;" aria-expanded="false">
            {{$account->name}}
                <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
            </a>
        @endif
    @if (count($account->children) > 0)
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach($account->children as $account)
                <?php $p_link .= $account->link?> //the $p_link is not defined here
                 @include('frontend.template.subaccount', array('p_link' => $account->link))
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif
</li>
```

However, when I tried to access the variable `p_link` in the `subaccount.blade.php` in the statement `<?php $p_link .= $account->link?>`, there is an error that says `the variable $p_link is not defined` despite being passed from the `navaccount.blade.php`.

What is the correct way to pass a variable in an `@include` and how to access the passed variable?

Comment: Where are oyu using $p_link in the subaccount.blade.php file?

Comment: Oh i think you are using the wrong values in your subaccount.blade.php file. See my answer so i can post code

Comment: I removed it because there was an error. I just tried to echo the variable

Comment: Please see my edited question. thanks

Comment: When you get the error is it on the first use of subaccount, or is it on the second use?

Comment: In the second use, I could not do `<?php $p_link .= $account->link?>` despite passing the variable in the first template `@include('frontend.template.subaccount', array('p_link' => $p_link))`

Answer (score 1):

In your foreach loop in the subaccount.blade.php file you are calling

```
@foreach($account->children as $account)
```

You are overwriting the $account object with the child.

you should change it to

```
@foreach($account->children as $child)
```

I'm not sure why you are naming the value p_link as you never use p_link in the view. Why not pass it in like this

```
@foreach($account->children as $child)
    @include('frontend.template.subaccount', array('account' => $child))
@endforeach
```

Comment: Actually, I want to access the link of the parent too, that's why I need one variable to passed the parent's link from navaccount.blade.template to the  subaccount.blade.template so that the variable `$p_link .= $child->link`;

Comment: @PriskaAprilia  you still need to fix the foreach loop.

Comment: I fixed it. But I still could not access the `$p_link` variable passed from `frontend.template.navaccount`. Please you can see my edited question.